# What is written on the schoolboy's pink shirt on the ending credit?

Tags: japanese-language, daily-lives-of-high-school-boys

[image]

On the ending credit, what is written on the guy's pink shirt which he is trying to show so badly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shirt says "Shota Moe", "Shota" as in little boy like "Loli" for little girl. As for why, he probably acts as one of the weirdos that the "heroes" are supposed to defeat in a crappy piece of play.

Comment: Please correct if wrong but it might be worthwhile to add that Shota Moe means the genre of cute little boys in a borderline pedophilia context. So "weirdo" makes a lot of sense